# Writing R package that call Fortran library using .fortran()

Tags: r, namespaces, fortran, package, shared-objects

Referring to  [Writing R package that call Fortran library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31630345/writing-r-package-that-call-fortran-library),

I have a very similar issue with my R package installation. I did install the package, but got an error in R after calling the library:

> library(NEpidemic)
>
> random_epi()
>
> Error in .Fortran("random_epi",   : 
>     "random_pi" not resolved from current namespace (NEpidemic)

Then I tried the same way as mentioned in the post by Ignacio, by adding useDynLib(random_epi) in the namespace file. But it gave an error saying that it couldn't install my package. 
Error:

> Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
>     shared object ‘random_epi.so’ not found
>
> Error: loading failed

I could see the .so file for the package name, i.e. NEpidemic.so, but not for the subroutine codes in SRC folder. I can see only random_epi.o

Comment: Are you using packrat?

Comment: @Hack-R  No.  I'm using Mac os x El Capitan with Xcode 7 and gfortran 6.1, R 3.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this issue. Edited namespace file.

Refer: 
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.mac/9789